# Vue use v-model and :value at the same time

Tags: vue.js, v-model

I'm trying to get the selected image value and sent it to the database. Right now I can send only the input value to the database but I need that value to be the selected image. Basically I need to use v-model and :value at the same time, right now the input value is empty.

```html
<img class="head" :src="head" v-if="head" @click="loadHead();">
<img class="body" :src="body" v-if="body" @click="loadBody();">
<img class="feet" :src="feet" v-if="feet" @click="loadFeet();">
<div class="row name justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Valitud pea:</label>
            <input class="valikud" v-model="post.head"><b>Valitud pea: </b> {{head}}>
            <pre>{{ head }}</pre>
            <p class="valikud" v-if="body"><b>Valitud keha: </b> {{body}}</p>
            <p class="valikud" v-if="feet"><b>Valitud jalad: </b> {{feet}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's your JavaScript code?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default data when your component is mounted.

```
mounted () {
    if (this.post.head === '') {
        this.post.head = this.head
    }
}
```